# Making the cards clickable

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, web-frontend

I want to make the cards clickable and a popup shows up. Here's the code

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
      {% for product in products %}
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ base64.b64encode(product[3]).decode() }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ product[1] }}">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product[0] }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product[1] }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">&dollar; {{ product[2] }}</p>
            <form method="POST" action="/store">
              <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="{{ product[0] }}">
              <button type="submit" class="add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>

<style>
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  padding-left: 40px; /* Add space for the minus button */
  padding-right: 40px; /* Add space for the plus button */
}
  .button_minus {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #095776;
  }

  .button_minus:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 4px;
    width: 50%;
    background: #095776;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }

  .button_minus:hover:after {
    background: #fff;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }

  .button_minus:hover {
    background-color: #095776;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }

    .button_plus {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #095776;
}

.button_plus:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #095776;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.button_plus:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #095776;
  height: 50%;
  width: 4px;
}

.button_plus:hover:before,
.button_plus:hover:after {
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.button_plus:hover {
  background-color: #095776;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

</style>
{% endblock %}
```

How should I go about doing that? I have tried to define the 'product' in JavaScript by moving it in the for loop and use the product variable in the loop.

I then wrap the JavaScript code in a loop that iterates over the products array and sets up event listeners for each product card.

But none of these worked. What should I do??

Comment: what JS Framework are you using?

Comment: maybe `<div class="card h-100" onclick='something'>` ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).